# Symfony1.4 with hundred apps

Tags: performance, cron, symfony-1.4

I have a huge site built with Symfony1.4, and it have about 600/700 apps.
With a cronjob it automatically create new apps when something happens, so, let's say that we create 5 new apps per day.
Now, my problem is that when the system create the app, after I launch the command for clear the cache and repair the permissions:

```
php symfony cc;
php symfony project:permissions
```

But, doing this, with 7 hundred apps, my server become extremly slowly, and sometimes become even unreachable.

How can I sole this?
Can anyone give us a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

*Woow 600/700 apps :o*

Anyway, I think you should better use a shell script to do this kind of actions (since you don't really need the symfony environment to execute these tasks).

Basically, `symfony cc` remove what's inside cache folder, so, you can run `rm -Rf cache/*` instead, it could be much faster.

For permissions part, you can run these commands:

```
# permission on global dirs
chmod 777 web/uploads
chmod 777 cache
chmod 777 log
chmod 777 symfony

# permissions on every thing inside cache, upload & log dir
find cache -type f -print | xargs chmod 666
find web/upload -type f -print | xargs chmod 666
find log -type f -print | xargs chmod 666

find cache -type d -print | xargs chmod 777
find web/upload -type d -print | xargs chmod 777
find log -type d -print | xargs chmod 777
```

Comment: ...interesting...I'll try it as soon as possible :)

Comment: Sorry but, for clearing the cache isn't better to execute "find . -type f -delete"? Doing so, I can avoid to remove directories too, which is better in term of performace...isn't it?

Comment: @ilSavo I don't know, you should do some benchmarks about that